# Nested Styled Component doesn-t overwrite style

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

Why h1 with "FFFFF" content is not white?
I want to understand why hex code is applied and not white color when it should be white. It's nested, styles should overwrite "weaker" style.

One solution is that scss output from styled components overwrite this white color and changes order in styles, so in styles this class with selector n color white is wrote above hex color and it's overwritten.
But if this is true it doesnt make sense... Styled Components creates sometimes order randomly?

[image: See this example here]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

It's not random, the order is based on **specificity**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

The higher the selector's specificity, the higher it's styling order.

Here's a nice tool to use: https://specificity.keegan.st/

You can also "cheat" the specificity by adding !important at the end, for example:

```
.dmZSNm h1 {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes, I know what specifity is. But in my case, white should overwrite hex code color. Styles for white color should be under component with hex, so it should be stronger in hierarchy, yes? Firts I defined component with hex color style. Next, nested component with white. So css output from this shoul look like class selector with white color is UNDER class selector color hex codem. It should be stronger